execute function before switching story (Storybook)
I want to execute function like destructor before openning other story on Storybook. Can I do that?
What I want to do is probably like lifecycle hooks in SPA. ngOnDestroy in Angular, ummounted in Vue.
When using addon, there are some apis. But I don't need to publish an addon. I only want to use it in my personal project.
